# Not able to set text in edit text from cloud firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-edittext

[image: This is Image of edit_note activity. Here content text is not showing]After opening notes I see textview of my note's title and content. I want to edit notes. But there is a problem with the edit note activity. It shows only the text of title in edittext. But below this content text not shown. I tried many ways like I tried to check what's a problem I put data of title. But it is also not showing the title. Means upper title edit text can show title data and content data but second edit text doesn't show title data and content data.

This is notes_open.class

```
public class notes_open extends AppCompatActivity {
        Intent data;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_notes_open);
            Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    
           data= getIntent();
            TextView MyTitle = findViewById(R.id.notesopentitle);
            TextView MyContent= findViewById(R.id.notesopencontent);
            MyContent.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    
    
    
    
            MyTitle.setText(data.getStringExtra("ourtitle"));
            MyContent.setText(data.getStringExtra("ourcontent"));
    
    
    
            FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });
        }
        @Override
    
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            MenuInflater inflater= getMenuInflater();
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.notesopen, menu);
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch(item.getItemId()){
                case  android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                case R.id.edit_note:
                    Intent i =  new Intent(getApplication(),edit_note.class);
                    i.putExtra("ourtitle",data.getStringExtra("ourtitle"));
                    i.putExtra("ourcontent",data.getStringExtra("ourcontent"));
                    startActivity(i);
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Below is edit_note.class

```
public class edit_note extends AppCompatActivity {
Intent data;
EditText edit_title,  edit_note;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_note);
        data =  getIntent();

        edit_title =  findViewById(R.id.edit_ttile);
        edit_note =  findViewById(R.id.edit_note);
        String edititle =  data.getStringExtra("ourtitle");
        String editcontent =  data.getStringExtra("ourcontent");
        try {


            edit_title.setText(edititle);
            edit_note.setText(editcontent);



}catch (NullPointerException ignore){}
    }
}
```

Edit note xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".edit_note">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_ttile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Title"
        android:layout_below="@id/appBarLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="56dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Content"
        android:layout_below="@id/edit_ttile"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="56dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Still unclear please post img to understand

Comment: please check this

Comment: did you try to console if you're retrieving data or no ?

Comment: how can you describe that

Comment: please check if you're retriving the both values in edit_note activity.

Comment: yes, I am retrieving both values

Comment: Do share you edit note's xml file i.e. activity_edit_note

Comment: please check i posted edit note xml

Comment: @Jomer i posted answer might help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your edittext assigning is wrong :

```
edit_note =  findViewById(R.id.edit_note);
```

Instead it needs :

```
edit_note =  findViewById(R.id.edit_content);
```

Comment: oh thanks man,  you have good problem solving skill